# iOS - How to get form data for an HTTP post

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, post

When submitting an HTTP post using Objective-C to a server, the required form data entries include `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTVALIDATION`, username, and password.  I get the user's username and password programmatically through the iOS application, but I hard-code the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` parameters by looking at their entries through Google Chrome Developer Tools.  The problem is that once the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` parameters change, my app is defunct.

Is it possible to get the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` parameters programmatically, possibly by storing them in a cookie, or can I send a POST request without them?  Do I need to integrate a JavaScript function into my Xcode project?

Comment: How do you submit an HTTP post through Xcode? Does Xcode have some sort-of built-in HTTP client? -.-"

Answer (score 0):

It's strongly related to your server-side logic because it's a deal of client and server applications how to use this parameters, but in in most cases VIEWSTATE paramater is given to you at previous request. You should not send it with first request. For example:

- request1, authorization — sending username, password. This will (may) return you VIEWSTATE.
- request2 — sending VIEWSTATE from request1 and other parameters. This will (may) return you new VIEWSTATE.
- request3 — sending VIEWSTATE from request2 and other parameters. This will (may) return you new VIEWSTATE.
- ...

I'm not aware about __EVENTVALIDATION parameter but you can inspect actual traffic from browser using debugging proxy tool such as Fiddler and try to find out logic of it's usage.